# CSS-Sub menu disappears on hover but displays sub sub menu's

Tags: css

When I hover over menu it displays the sub menu. And if i hover over sub menu it displays the sub sub menu but the sub menu disappears.
Ex. test test-1 test-2 is the menu and test-2 contains 3 sub menus like test-21 test-22 test-23.
and the test-21 contains 2 sub sub menu like test-211 test-212. If i hover over test-2, it displays test-21, test-22, test-23. And if I hover over test-21 it displays test-211, test-212 but test-21 disappears.

Comment: Where's the snippet?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

h1,p {
 text-align:center;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
 }

h1 {
 font-size:60px;
}

p {
  font-size:20px;
}

nav { margin:100px auto; width:800px; }

nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display:block;
 }
 
nav ul li {
 float:left;
 display:list-item;
 list-style: none; 
 
 background-color:#64abfb;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #2ecc71;
 }

nav ul li a {
 display:block;
 padding:15px 10px; 
 
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:20px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
}

li a:hover { background-color: #2ecc71; }

 
/* Change this in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content: ' »'; } 
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }   
 
 
/* The Dropdown Styles */
/* =================== */

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute; top: 58px;
}
 
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:list-item;
}
 
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
 width:170px;
 float:none;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom:none;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers */
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: absolute relative;
 top:-58px; 
 left:170px;
}
```

```html
<p>Dropdowns are marked with " » "<br/>
</p>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WordPress</a>
        <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        </ul>        
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
        <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
         <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```